# Getting the exact position of a specific OpCode in a binary file

Tags: c, binary, opcode, objdump, disassembly

Our professor in computer-architecture gave us a sample program which asks for a password. The task is to change the jump-opcode after it compares the entered password and decides if it is okay or not.
I wrote a program which can change any byte at a specific place in a given binary file.

Here's the code of the pasword-program:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char *pw = "12441233";
    char pass[32];

    printf("Enter password:\n");

    scanf("%s", pass);

    if(strncmp(pass,pw,8))
    {
        printf("Password wrong\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("Welcome\n");
}
```

So I entered `$ objdump -d task` in the console and got this:

> ...
>
> 400703: || 48 8b 5d e8  || mov -0x18(%rbp),%rbx
>
> 400707: ||   64 48 33 1c 25 28 00 || xor    %fs:0x28,%rbx
>
> 40070e: ||   00 00
>
> **400710:    || 74 05                    || je     400717**
>
> 400712:  || e8 29 fe ff ff           || callq  400540 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
>
> 400717: ||   48 83 c4 58         ||  add   $0x58,%rsp
>
> 40071b:  || 5b                ||     pop    %rbx
>
> ...

`74` is the byte for **je** which I want to change to `75` for **jne**.
How can I get the exact position of my `74` byte in the corresponding binary file so that I can change it to a new value?

Comment: The location in memory has very little to do with the location in the file.  You know the byte values before and after 74 05.  Search the file for those.

Comment: i know that the memory adress has nothing to do with it, that's why i'm asking what else i should do. I need it for my change program it looks like this: changebyte -d POSITION BYTE OLDFILE NEWFILE. I think i found the corresponding byte via the binary-editor search function but for the required solution i need a reproducable wy to find the position in the binary.

Comment: Is this linux or windows? I can give you an answer for windows executable.

Comment: This particular problem is on a linux system. I'd be happy to hear the windows-solution, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hans noted, the memory location has nothing to do with it.  What you need to do is find where the byte (or bytes) are located in the file.  For this a really good disassembler (this would be IDA-Pro) makes you live very easy.  Sadly, there is a steep price curve for IDA, so we will stick to tools that you can get easily.

What follows was done on a Linux machine, using gcc version 4.8.2 and gdb 7.7 running on an Ubuntu 14.04

1. Compiled the code using `gcc -g -ansi -pedantic -Wall`.  Not really an issue, but `main` should have a return value.
2. Loaded the program into gdb, put a break point at main and then ran the program.  When I hit the break point, I used gdb's `disass` command to get a disassembly listing as shown below:

   ```
      (gdb) disass
      Dump of assembler code for function main:
      0x000000000040067d <+0>:     push   %rbp
      0x000000000040067e <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
      0x0000000000400681 <+4>:     push   %rbx
      0x0000000000400682 <+5>:     sub    $0x58,%rsp
      0x0000000000400686 <+9>:     mov    %edi,-0x54(%rbp)
      0x0000000000400689 <+12>:    mov    %rsi,-0x60(%rbp)
   => 0x000000000040068d <+16>:    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
      0x0000000000400696 <+25>:    mov    %rax,-0x18(%rbp)
      0x000000000040069a <+29>:    xor    %eax,%eax
           [ ... ]
      0x00000000004006cc <+79>:    mov    $0x8,%edx
      0x00000000004006d1 <+84>:    mov    %rcx,%rsi
      0x00000000004006d4 <+87>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
      0x00000000004006d7 <+90>:    callq  0x400520 <strncmp@plt>
      0x00000000004006dc <+95>:    test   %eax,%eax
      0x00000000004006de <+97>:    je     0x4006f4 <main+119>
      0x00000000004006e0 <+99>:    mov    $0x4007c0,%edi
      0x00000000004006e5 <+104>:   callq  0x400530 <puts@plt>
           [ ... ]
      0x0000000000400718 <+155>:   retq   
      End of assembler dump.
   ```
3. Pretty ominous looking, I know but take a second and look around and notice a few things;
   a. The numbers in the angle-brackets (*i.e.* <+97>) give the number of bytes that the instruction is located from the start of the function.  In your case the the op-code that you need is 97 bytes from the beginning of the function.
   b. The first 9 bytes (the first four instructions) will normally look like what we have here, they are the prolog for the function, and they are setting up the activation (or stack) frame for the function.
4. Now, we need to find where main is in your executable.  This tends to be OS and compiler specific.  In my case, working on a Linux host, I know that the code is stored in the **.text** section of the file, and I can use the tool `readelf` to get that location as shown below;

   ```
   readelf --wide -S task
   There are 35 section headers, starting at offset 0x1478:

   Section Headers:
     [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
     [ 0]                   NULL            0000000000000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
     [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS        0000000000400238 000238 00001c 00   A  0   0  1
     [ 2] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE            0000000000400254 000254 000020 00   A  0   0  4
     [ 3] .note.gnu.build-id NOTE            0000000000400274 000274 000024 00   A  0   0  4
     [ 4] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH        0000000000400298 000298 00001c 00   A  5   0  8
     [ 5] .dynsym           DYNSYM          00000000004002b8 0002b8 0000c0 18   
               [ .... ]
     [13] .text             PROGBITS        0000000000400590 000590 000202 00  AX  0   0 16
     [14] .fini             PROGBITS        0000000000400794 000794 000009 00  AX  0   0  4
     [15] .rodata           PROGBITS        00000000004007a0 0007a0 000037 00   
   Key to Flags:
     W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), l (large)
     I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
     O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)
   ```
5. From the above, we can see that the **.text** section will start at a memory location of 0x400590 and an ending location of 0x400792 (based on a size of 0x202).  Additionally, we can see the the **.text** section has an offset in the file of 0x590.  Looking back at our disassembly, we can see that `main` starts at 0x0040067d, which is in the range of **.text** (just a sanity check).
6. We now have the entry point for the application (the starting memory address of the **.text** section, and if we subtract the starting point of `main` from the entry point, we *should* get the offset (in memory) for `main` relative to where the code is mapped.  Finally adding this value to the offset of the code in the executable *should* give us the file location of `main`:

   ```
   000067d: 5548 89e5 5348 83ec 5889 7dac 4889 75a0  UH..SH..X.}.H.u.
   000068d: 6448 8b04 2528 0000 0048 8945 e831 c048  dH..%(...H.E.1.H
   000069d: c745 b8a4 0740 00bf ad07 4000 e882 feff  .E...@....@.....
   00006ad: ff48 8d45 c048 89c6 bfbd 0740 00b8 0000  .H.E.H.....@....
   00006bd: 0000 e8ac feff ff48 8b4d b848 8d45 c0ba  .......H.M.H.E..
   00006cd: 0800 0000 4889 ce48 89c7 e844 feff ff85  ....H..H...D....
   00006dd: c074 14bf c007 4000 e846 feff ffbf ffff  .t....@..F......
   00006ed: ffff e88c feff ffbf cf07 4000 e832 feff  ..........@..2..
   00006fd: ff48 8b5d e864 4833 1c25 2800 0000 7405  .H.].dH3.%(...t.
   000070d: e82e feff ff48 83c4 585b 5d              .....H..X[]
   ```
7. As a quick sanity check, remember I mentioned that the first few bytes of main from the disassembly of main were fairly boiler-plate, if we look at them and assemble them into we machine we get:

   ```
     push   %rbp             0x55
     mov    %rsp,%rbp        0x48 0x89 0xe5
     push   %rbx             0x53
     sub    $0x58,%rsp       0x48 0x83 0xec 0x58
     mov    %edi,-0x54(%rbp) 0x89 0x7d 0xac
   ```
8. Given that the above sequences of bytes matches the begging sequence of bytes from step 5, it is a fairly safe assumption that we have found the location of `main` in the executable.  Now all that is left to do is to modify the byte at offset 0x6de from 0x74 to 0x73.

N.B. IDA does have a free version, with a number of restrictions on it, so it would be worth your time to grab it and play with it.

Hope this help,
T

Comment: Thank you very much, this explained a great deal to me. Thanks again for the very good explenation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `readelf` utility and look for the `LOAD` Program Headers. They give the mapping between the addresses `objdump` is showing you (`VirtAddr`, aka `p_vaddr`) and the offsets in the file (`PhysAddr`, aka `p_paddr`).